# How to detect an a dropped SSE (server sent event) client using Axum?

Tags: rust, server-sent-events, rust-axum

In the below code I'm handling sse connections within the function `sse_handler()`. Is there a way to know when that connection is closed so I can remove the client from `Bradcaster.inner.clients`?

REPL: https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/xkqyt2

```rs
/*
[dependencies]
axum = { version = "0.6.20" }
futures = { version = "0.3.28", default-features = false }
tokio = { version = "1.32.0", default-features = false, features = [
    "macros",
    "process",
    "rt-multi-thread",
] }
tokio-stream = { version = "0.1.14", default-features = false, features = [
    "sync",
] }
*/

use axum::{
    extract::State,
    response::{
        sse::{Event, KeepAlive, Sse},
        Html,
    },
    routing::get,
    Router,
};
use futures::stream::Stream;
use tokio_stream::{wrappers::ReceiverStream, StreamExt};
use std::{
    convert::Infallible,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

struct BroadcasterInner {
    clients: Vec<mpsc::Sender<String>>,
}

pub struct Broadcaster {
    inner: Mutex<BroadcasterInner>,
}

struct AppState {
    broadcaster: Arc<Broadcaster>,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let broadcaster = Broadcaster::new();

    let app_state = Arc::new(AppState { broadcaster });

    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/send_message", get(send_message))
        .route("/sse", get(sse_handler))
        .with_state(app_state);

    axum::Server::bind(&"0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap())
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

async fn send_message(State(app_state): State<Arc<AppState>>) -> Html<&'static str> {
    app_state.broadcaster.broadcast("message").await;

    Html("Message sent")
}

async fn sse_handler(
    State(app_state): State<Arc<AppState>>,
) -> Sse<impl Stream<Item = Result<Event, Infallible>>> {
    let rx = app_state.broadcaster.add_client().await;

    let mystream = ReceiverStream::<String>::new(rx).map(|res| Ok(Event::default().data(res)));

    Sse::new(mystream).keep_alive(KeepAlive::default())
}

impl Broadcaster {
    pub fn new() -> Arc<Self> {
        Arc::new(Broadcaster {
            inner: Mutex::new(BroadcasterInner {
                clients: Vec::new(),
            }),
        })
    }

    pub async fn add_client(&self) -> mpsc::Receiver<String> {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<String>(10);

        tx.send("welcome".to_string()).await.unwrap();

        self.inner.lock().unwrap().clients.push(tx);

        rx
    }

    pub async fn broadcast(&self, event: &str) {
        let clients = self.inner.lock().unwrap().clients.clone();

        let send_futures = clients.iter().map(|client| client.send(event.to_string()));

        let _ = futures::future::join_all(send_futures).await;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). (However, the context you've provided in the code sample makes it much easier to see the "X" than it usually is with these kinds of questions, and that is very much appreciated!)

---

The answer to the "X" part is that it looks like you actually want a [`tokio::sync::broadcast`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/broadcast/index.html) channel.  Using a broadcast channel will generally *just work* as you don't have to do anything to handle a closed connection because there is only one sender.

---

The answer to the "Y" part is that when the connection is closed, the response value gets dropped.  This will transitively drop `rx`, which closes the channel.  The `broadcast` function will receive an error from the `send` call for senders whose receivers are all gone, so you can react to this error in `broadcast` to clean up orphaned senders.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind change the code in REPL, here: https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/xkqyt2?